# Why do I have duplicate contact birthdays on Android calendar?

Tags: contacts, calendar, htc-droid-incredible

I deleted all of my contacts from Google and from my HTC incredible so that I could reload them all in just Google. As a result, the calendar on my phone has 2 entries on the "contacts birthdays and events" calendar on my phone. The calendar in my Google account only has 1 entry. The android calendar even has a birthday for a contact I deleted.

Has anyone else seen this and have a fix?

Comment: Are the duplicate entries in different calendars (IE different colored labels?)

Comment: no, they are in the same calendar. i already tried turning off that calendar and turning it back on to force it to re-sync completely with the online google calendar, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

"
TomSawyer_2112

Hey Guys,

I had to clear the Calendar Data for the Bday to show on my calendar. This is what I did,
Go to Settings-Applications-Manage applications, then select Calendar Storage then "delete data". After doing this the screen (HTC EVO) will reboot (white screen with the HTC Logo).

After clearing the data, go to the calendar setting and add the Bbay.

Hope this work for you.
"

Source:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=58d284f1a1f36866&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Remove the google-account from your android system (sync settings), than add it again. After that, go into your contacts and refresh / resync your contacts. Now take a look at your calendar, it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into your address book, select the contact to edit, and then delete the event (in your case, birthday). Then click save. Now, on the calendar, it should only show one entry for the birthday.